# Deploying SSRS Reports using RS utility

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012, rs.exe

I am currently deploying SSRS reports from my client machine to the report server, using Visual Studio.  I am interested in automating the deployment using the RS.exe utility.  The report server machine/box is within our network, but it is a remote server.  I was wondering if I could use the RS.exe utility that is on my local machine to execute a script (locally from my client machine) to deploy the local RDL's to the report server.  What I am asking is if it is necessary to run the RS.exe utility/script from the Report Server machine, or if it would be possible to run it from my client machine.  Thanks kindly in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a direct answer to your question, yes you can run RS utility to run from your client machine, providing that you have the appropriate permissions on the report server that you are deploying to.